# How to add dynamic selected option to a dynamically populated select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm trying to set the selected option text for a select menu to be whatever `location` is - this parameter has been passed into the `updateDepartment` function dynamically from a previous PHP request.

The AJAX function that follows calls to another PHP file to dynamically populate the `#editDepartmentLocation` select menu with a list of text/value option pairs. One of the `name`s in this list will always match whatever `location` parameter is passed into the function.

I'm able to set the value of `#editDepartmentName` to the name parameter as this is just a text input, however when I try to add `$("#editDepartmentName").val(location)` this does not work and the selected option just defaults to the item at the top of the list, even though the value of `location` is present in the list.

Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks for any help.

JS:

```
function updateDepartment(name, id, location) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getLocation.php",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                $.each(result.data, i => {
                    $('#editDepartmentLocation').append($("<option>", {
                        text: result.data[i].name,
                        value: result.data[i].id,
                    }));
                });
            };
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
});

    $("#editDepartmentName").val(name);
    $("#editDepartmentLocation").val(location);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="editDepartmentName" required>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="location">Location:</label>
                <select class="form-control custom-select" id="editDepartmentLocation" required>
                </select>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is async, so "editDepartmentLocation" is most likely not populated yet.
Try moving:

```
$("#editDepartmentName").val(name);
$("#editDepartmentLocation").val(location);
```

Inside the success function. Or do a comparison like:

```
var option =  $("<option>", {
                    text: result.data[i].name,
                    value: result.data[i].id,
});

if (result.data[i].id == location){
    option.attr("selected", "selected");
}

$('#editDepartmentLocation').append(option);
```